# How to write Dynamic sql query using loops

Tags: php, mysql

[image: please check the image]. [image]

I'm trying to write a query to fetch the data from the database, but am not getting. I want to fetch the title of ConstituencyId 3. For 3rd constituency, I have to display 4 different titles. if a user selects constituency 2 and 3 I have to display titles of 2nd and 3rd Constituency.

```
SELECT N1.Id, N1.Title From NewsContent N1
Where N1.Id > 0 and  
(N1.ConstituencyId like ('%2%') OR N1.ConstituencyId Like ('%3') OR N1.ConstituencyId like ('%4%'));
```

This is the equery I have to write dynamically because I don't know what the user selects. am not getting in dynamically. Please help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET` here, e.g.

```
SELECT N1.Id, N1.Title
FROM NewsContent N1
WHERE
    N1.Id > 0 AND
    FIND_IN_SET('2', N1.ConstituencyId) > 0 AND
    FIND_IN_SET('3', N1.ConstituencyId) > 0;
```

But note that storing CSV in the `ConstituencyId` column means that your table is not completely normalized.  This is not ideal, for the above reason that it makes querying difficult, and updating even more difficult.  Fortunately, MySQL has a `FIND_IN_SET` function which can help, but we should avoid relying on it.

Comment: if user selects more than 5 options how can i write

Comment: You would need five separate calls to `FIND_IN_SET`, _unless_ you can tell me that you store your IDs in ascending/descending order in the `ConstituencyId` column.  In that case, I could give you another option.

Comment: if user selects more than 100 options, How would i know, that how many options are selected, So am expecting the loop. if we write the loop , it will run automatically..

Comment: If you really have this requirement, then you should take my advice and _stop_ storing CSV data in your tables.

Comment: what is your advice?

Comment: Store each constituency ID in a separate record.  This is the setup which databases expect.

Comment: In some situations one particular item is might be common for some Constituencies. If item is common for 20 constituencies now i no need to repeat that item 20 times. Now ill give those 20 Ids to that item.  Thats why am doing like this. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Space in a database is not as precious as you seem to think.  Nothing at all wrong with having a table which maps constituencies to some other column.